# Why does this img attribute not work?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and my question is about the img tag. I tried to change the border-width and border-color attribute in the style tag in head tag but it does not seem to work. I tried with border and other attributes. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to get my head around it but there is not a useful error message or anything.

Here is the code:

```css
hr {
  width: 85%
}

p {
  text-align: center
}

figure {
  text-align: center
}

body {
  background-color: lightyellow
}

.fig1 {
  border-width: 100px;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p> Hello, I am Stephane Nouafo and this is my main web page. </p> <br>
<figure>
  <img class="fig1" src="https://thepsychologist.bps.org.uk/sites/thepsychologist.bps.org.uk/files/brain.jpg" alt="The Brain">
  <figcaption> The Brain: Logic, creativity and a whole lot more</figcaption>
</figure> <br>
<p> Enjoy!! </p>
<hr>
<p> I appreciate looking at the following websites: <br> </p>
<ul>
  <li> <a href="www.youtube.com"> Youtube </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="www.google.com"> Google </a> </li>
  <li> Best blog, aka <a href="www.waitbutwhy.com"> WaitButWhy </a> </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<p> Here are some quotes I enjoy: <br> - "This quote" -By Me - "This other quote" -By this person
</p>
<hr>
<pre> Here is a piece of code I wrote and what it does: <br>
        Code: <br>
        What it does: <br>
        </pre>
<hr>
<a href="lesson.html"> Link </a> to my lesson.
```

Comment: what is wrong? The border doesn't show?

Comment: can you also share your CSS?

Comment: Instead of posting your entire page, only post the tag you are trying to understand. Also, post the code that you expect to work and doesn't. Make sure you first read the [Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) (currently applying HTML standard). If that seems too complicated, here's a more friendly [trustworthy resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Comment: It's better the shorthand border. Using it you won't forget one of the properties. "border: 100px solid blue;" will work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the border style for .fig1.
This will work:

```
.fig1 {border-width:100px; border-color: blue; border-style: solid;}
```

Shorthand for the same:

```
.fig1 { border: 100px solid blue; }
```

Link to working snippet: http://jsbin.com/zicepedono/edit?html,output

Documentation on the border property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Edit: As user Andrei Gheorghiu pointed out in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48271460/3714697) below, the default value for the `border-style` attribute is `none` and so the border will not be shown by default unless that value is changed, even if the `border-width` property is set.

Comment: Comment on why this is downvoted please?

Comment: I down-voted (and added my answer) because you initially didn't pinpoint the source of the problem. For OP, it's a lot more important to explain exactly what's going on rather than providing an example that works. So I considered your answer to be less than helpful, for both OP and future visitors struggling at the same level. Since you now specified it, I changed my vote. Happy coding!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu That's fair enough :) Thanks, lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

The [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) of `border-style` attribute is `none`. Unless you change it to another valid value, adding `border-width` won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use this border shorthand property.

```
.fig1 {
    border: 100px solid blue;
}
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp for reference

Answer (score 0):

You need ALL 3 border properties in order to show the border:

1) border-width
2) border-color
3) border-style

You only had 2 out of 3:

1) border-width
2) border-color

So if you just add border-style, you should see your border:

```
border-style: solid
```

Alternatively, you can use a shorthand to specify these 3 properties:

```
border: 100px solid blue;
```